# C# Binarysearch gives inconsistent results

Tags: c#

I have a code the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<double> test = new List<double> {-1, 11, 11, 24, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 34};

    Console.WriteLine(LeftSegmentIndex(test, 30));
}

public static int LeftSegmentIndex(List<double> Norm, int t)
{
    int index = Norm.BinarySearch(t);
    if (index < 0)
    {
        index = ~index;
    }
    return Math.Min(Math.Max(index, 0), Norm.Count);
}
```

this code compares a raw score against a test stanine score and outputs the index of the stanine or the next one if it isn't exact. Now the strange thing here is that when i give a raw score of 11, the result is 1. Which is logical because when the first 11 is hit from the list, the code breaks and returns index 1.

Now when i give a raw score of 30, the program skips the first 30 and outputs the second one so the result is 7 instead of 6. Can someone please explain why this is happening?

Comment: From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=net-5.0#System_Collections_Generic_List_1_BinarySearch__0_): "*If the List<T> contains more than one element with the same value, the method returns only one of the occurrences, and it might return any one of the occurrences, not necessarily the first one.*"

Comment: This is nothing strange. That's how binary search works. It splits the list in half and checks whether the searched item is left or right of the "middle{ point, and repeats with the proper part. This means the result in case of duplicates depends on the total size of the list and the contents themselves